# Updating tables from generate_series(int, int) function Postgres 9.0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with data in it I want to keep, but I have to add a new column of integers for ordering purposes. Now this ordering will be different depending on the clientID as each different client wants different ordering. So in my example there are 3 different clients, the first client has 10 rows of data the second has 15, and the third has 87. So basically I'm looking for a query that will let me update the ordering column in a way that will allow me to do a select on the table that would give results like this.

```
Select ordering from table Where clientID = 1 
-----------
Ordering
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Now the query I'm currently using to do this is

```
UPDATE data SET ordering = generate_series
FROM (SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,87)) as k <
where  clientid = '3'
```

This will update all the correct rows but only with the first value, so all the values in ordering would be 1. I feel like I'm missing something here or this just doesn't work in postgres as it does in other SQL languages. Any solution here will help I would also like to know why my update would not work as I expected in postgres. Also I cannot change versions of postgres based on the environment I work in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would need `generate_series()`. A window function that numbers all rows for each client should do:

```
update data 
   set ordering = t.rn
  from (select pk_column, 
               row_number() over (partition by clientid  order by pk_column) as rn
          from data
       ) t
where t.pk_column = data.pk_column;
```

`pk_column` is the primary key column of the table `data`